# Is there a way to install Utopia Documents on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?

Tags: apt, 16.04

I wanted to know if there was a way to install Utopia Documents on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus). I checked the launchpad for a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/utopia-documents), however there are none for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If I try to install it via this [link](http://utopiadocs.com/linux/), I get the following error.

```
W: The repository 'http://utopiadocs.com/apt xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://utopiadocs.com/apt/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

Utopia Documents is available for previous releases of Ubuntu. Earlier I had Ubuntu 14.04 and I had successfully installed Utopia Documents on it using the same link.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of Utopia Documents (3.0) being released that will support Ubuntu Xenial. Once it's accepted by Debian it should appear in the repositories and at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/utopia-documents

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, utopia-documents is still not part of the ubuntu-16.04 repositories (state: Jul. 2018).

...However, it is maintained by the [NeuroDebian Neuroscience Software Platform](http://neuro.debian.net/), whose own repository can be accessed by installing the neurodebian software package of the ubuntu-16.04 repositories:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install neurodebian
```

Following the installation of the neurodebian package, simply update the   package index files from their source and install the utopia-documents package:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
:~$ sudo apt-get install utopia-documents
```